# Removing dynamically added scripts dynamically

Tags: jquery

I have the following which dynamically adds javascript and or jquery scripts to my page as and when needed:

```
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = url;
$("#someElement").append( script );
```

Is it possible to remove one of more of the scripts which have been added dynamically?  i.e. if `$("#someElement")` is `.remove`ed, will that also remove the script within it?

Comment: "if $("#someElement") is .removeed, will that also remove the script within it?" Ya, this will remove script tag, but why not test it yourself???

Comment: It wont do what he wants though, even though they're often served in the same file, HTML and JS are something different, removing the JS from HTML doesnt actually remove JS at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the first awnser here, couldnt explain it much better myself;
[Best way to load and unload JS file via JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738380/best-way-to-load-and-unload-js-file-via-jquery)

Basically, you cant, but you *can* work around that by unloading specifics (remove events, clear vars, etc) See the link for more info.