# How to provide a Spanish translation of my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, coding-style

**I'm a total newbie who is starting to work on jQuery and have minimum knowledge on the subject matter.**

I'm working on translating my entire website to another language from **English to Spanish, etc.** I don't want to burden the site and put all of the translation into 1 js file so I'm thinking if its possible to put a separate file for each translation like **english.js**, **spanish.js**, **japanese.js** and call the specific file when needed and unload others that are not needed. Please if anyone know any existing plugin to use for this approach please tell me.

For moving to one language to another I will be using a dropdown list.

Comment: You shouldn't be translating the site with JavaScript. Are you working within a framework?

Comment: I'm not sure what a framework is but I used HTML, CSS, and jQuery for my WebSite.

Comment: Are you using a backend scripting language like PHP, Ruby, Python, etc?

Comment: No. Just HTML, CSS and jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### No JavaScript required

Based on your comments, it seems like you have static HTML files, so this should be a breeze

```
<!-- example.com/en/index.html -->
<nav>
  <a href="/en/index.html">Home</a>
  <a href="/en/about/index.html">About</a>
  <a href="/es/index.html>Español</a>
</nav>

<p>
  Hello World
</p>
```

Then you could write the Spanish page like this

```
<!-- example.com/es/index.html -->
<nav>
  <a href="/es/index.html">Inicio</a>
  <a href="/es/about/index.html">Quienes Somos<a>
  <a href="/en/index.html">English</a>
</nav>

<p>
  ¡Hola Mundo!
</p>
```

The basic idea is you will have a separate version of each page of the site. If you have

- /en/index.html
- /en/foo.html
- /en/about/index.html
- /en/about/contact.html

Then you will also need

- /es/index.html
- /es/foo.html
- /es/about/index.html
- /es/about/contact.html

English files should have links relative to the English root `/en` and Spanish files should have all links relative to the the Spanish root `/es`

To make page switching easier on the user, the nav could have the language switcher keep the user on the same page, but just change the language

```
<!-- example.com/en/some/deep/page.html -->
<nav>
  <!-- ... -->
  <a href="/es/some/deep/page.html>Español</a>
</nav>
```

If the user is viewing `/en/some/deep/page.html` in English and they click the Español link, they will see `/es/some/deep/page.html` in Spanish without having to re-navigate back to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically to answer your question on loading and unloading JavaScript files, there is a brilliant response already on StackOverflow: [Best way to load and unload JS file via JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738380/best-way-to-load-and-unload-js-file-via-jquery) by Chris Pratt

But fundimentially you can't unload a JS once it's been loaded.

Maybe what you should look at is implementing language configuration on the server end, so when outputting the HTML it looks at a language file. If you are using PHP+Smarty for example it is made very easy.

Comment: I already looked in that thread but the .live() is already deprecated by jQuery so I'm not sure if that is still doable.