# Dynamically Remove Script file from html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I developed a website on which i navigate different html page from home page by calling load function like the following:

```
$("#content").load('page.html', function (response, status) {});
```

page.html contains some script file which also loaded in home page. What i am trying do is removing the script file dynamically when i navigate different page 
like that

```
$("#content").load('another_page.html', function (response, status) {
   if (status = "success") {
      //Remove script file in page.html
   }
});
```

This following process i have applied found by google

```
function removejscssfile(filename, filetype) {
   var targetelement = (filetype == "js") ? "script" : (filetype == "css") ? "link" : "none" //determine element type to create nodelist from
   var targetattr = (filetype == "js") ? "src" : (filetype == "css") ? "href" : "none" //determine corresponding attribute to test for
   var allsuspects = document.getElementsByTagName(targetelement)

   for (var i = allsuspects.length; i >= 0; i--) { //search backwards within nodelist for matching elements to remove
      if (allsuspects[i] && allsuspects[i].getAttribute(targetattr) != null && allsuspects[i].getAttribute(targetattr).indexOf(filename) != -1)
         allsuspects[i].parentNode.removeChild(allsuspects[i]) //remove element by calling parentNode.removeChild()
   }
}
```

but the script file still exist.

Comment: Once a js file has been loaded and run, I don't think it's as simple as removing the script tag. You have to make sure all the functions and variables it creates are `undefined`.

Comment: Yeah even if you remove the script node from the DOM, the script will still live in the JS runtime environment.

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738380/best-way-to-load-and-unload-js-file-via-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the script tag or removing the JS file tag won't discard the JS. He is still loaded. So you also need to tell him to erase this code.

One possible way is to encapsulate your Javascipt file into one function, and then redefine this function. For example :

```
function foo(){
    //Your javascript here
}
```

And then :

```
foo= function(){};
```

But if your function contains event, you still have to unbind them manually.